# php soap client __getLastRequest always same

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

```
<?php
$opt = array(
    'currentPage' => '1',
    'pageSize' => '10',
    'productType' => 'TICKET'
);
$url = 'http://x.x.x.x/clutter/services/distributionService?wsdl';
$client = new SoapClient($url, array("trace" => 1));
$result = $client->productInfoList(array('parameters' => $opt));
var_dump($client->__getFunctions());
var_dump($client->__getLastRequest());
var_dump($client->__getLastResponse());
```

Whatever I change the $opt that's the value pass to soap function, use __getLastRequest always return:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns1="http://service.distribution.xxxx.com"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:productInfoList><ns1:in0 xsi:nil="true"/></ns1:productInfoList></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

never change.
And I never get soap result correctly.
Looks parameters no passing in request. why?

### The response is soap XML. But it tell me params is wrong. I can't debug because __getLastRequest has no params inside ever.

Comment: What does `productInfoList()` do?

Comment: just a function of that soap webservice

Comment: In that case, you should be doing `$result = $client->__soapCall('productInfoList', array('parameters' => $opt));`.

Comment: Tried $client->__soapCall('productInfoList', array('parameters' => $opt)); same problem. request xml hasn't params.

Comment: What do you get if you `var_dump($result);`?

Comment: soap xml response. but not the result I want

Comment: @BenFortune thanks you. I don't know why __getLastRequest no params inside the request XML. other things looks ok. Response give me a error tell me check the params.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = $client->productInfoList(array('in0' => $str));
```

this works.

```
<ns1:in0 xsi:nil="true"/>
```

means there is one parameter named in0.

and should not passing Array.